# Magento's Mage::log() causes white screen

Tags: php, magento

When using Magentos log facility Mage::log() it sometimes causes a white screen. No error messages are outputted either to the screen or any of the log files (var/log/system.log, var/log/exception.log ) 
This seems to happen only when I'm trying to log a very large object. for example when I'm trying this

```
Mage::log(Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories());
```

inside a block controller it causes a white screen. 
the same happens when I'm trying to log the current product in `app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`
using

```
Mage::log($_product);
```

Usually Mage::log() works fine and writes everything to the system.log file. 
I was wondering if this has happened to anybody else or if anybody has an idea about why this is happening?

Comment: is there an error in (Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories()?
  is it reaching an OOM state or exceeding run time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Mage::log` works a lot like `print_r`, private and protected values are printed too which includes extensive resource details. You can avoid these by using the purpose made `Varien_Object::debug` method.

```
Mage::log($_product->debug());
```

`debug` is also preferred because it detects recursion which not all versions of PHP do.

Comment: Yeah, I tried print_r on a passed $Payment object... 4.5GB (RAM + swap), and 10 minutes of runtime later I'm still hitting OOM or run time errors.  With Zend appending all that data to every later of abstraction it makes print_r unusable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it happens to everyone.

Try not to log large objects.

In case you need I would advice you to use die.

for example like this

```
    $object = ...;
    die($object);
or
    die('pre html tag'.print_r($object,true).'pre html tag');
```